# Проблемы с кодировкой при получении заголовка страницы по url

Tags: php, кодировка

```
$content = file_get_contents($Url);
preg_match_all('#<title>.+</title>#', $content, $matches);
$title = preg_replace('#(<title>|</title>)#', '', $matches[0][0]);
```

Таким способом получаю заголовок из URL. Проблема в том, что не у всех сайтов одна и та же кодировка, из большинства сайтов получается извлечь заголовок, а вот у остальных нет, выводит ромбы с вопросительным знаков, в бд и вовсе не записывает.
Пытался перевести полученную строку в UTF-8, но пока безрезультатно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Определите кодировку функцией [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php).
2. Преобразуйте например в UTF-8 функцией [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
3. Затем парсите [регуляркой с модификатором](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `u` - utf-8.

> Этот модификатор включает дополнительную функциональность PCRE, которая не совместима с Perl: шаблон и целевая строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки.

`preg_match_all('#<title>.+?</title>#isu', $content, $matches);`

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам нужно определиться в какой кодировке Вы будете хранить страницы.

Потом Вам нужно определить кодировку скачанной страницы

Если кодировки отличаются - вызвать функцию `iconv()`

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
Определил кодировку страницы по url

```
preg_match_all('#charset=.+"#', $content, $array);
$charset = preg_replace('#(charset=|")#', '', $array[0][0]);
```

Но этот код не универсальный, т к не все страницы именно так указывают кодировку.
Затем, преобразовал строку в нужную кодировку

```
$newtitle = iconv($charset, "UTF-8", $title);
```

Конечно код не идеальный, но процент успешного извлечения заголовков значительно повысился.